# Reading already loaded properties in a jsp?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My JSP pages need to display different information depending on which environment they're in (dev, production, sandbox, etc). I want to have a properties file for each of these environments that contain all the parameters they might need. How can I reference the properties from this file in a JSP page? I am using spring and loading the properties as below. i have it in applicationcontext.xml file.

How can i get already loaded properties into jsp?

```
<bean id="proConfigPropertyFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>  
                <value>file:/someFolder/some.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the properties in your controller, and store it in the model:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("proConfigPropertyFactory")
private Properties configProperties;

public ModelAndView someMethod() {
    return new ModelAndView("TheJspName", "configProperties", configProperties);
}
```